# Oracle Stored Proc inserting encoded data

Tags: xml, oracle, stored-procedures, utf-8, oracle11g

I am looking into why we are getting some encoded data in our Database.

I found the grid we are using was adding some HTML Encoding to the xml data that was passed to a stored procedure.

However, I have turned off html encoding in the datatable, and confirmed we are sending un-encoded data to the database.  however, the stored proc that inserts/updates the data seems to still be encoding a single quote.

I do not see anything in the stored proc that says for it to encode the data.  Is there a setting or something else that could be sent with xml that could be causing this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE spSample (ncoXml IN XMLTYPE)
IS
```

The xml is being sent in with utf-8 encoding.  I am guessing this is the issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

Thanks for any help or advise you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure argument is XMLtype, which automatically encodes single and double quotes, from the [predefined XML entities list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML)

```
SQL> select xmltype('<test>6''4"</test>') from dual;

XMLTYPE('<TEST>6''4"</TEST>')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<test>6&apos;4&quot;</test>
```

This is nothing to do with HTML; other non-XML [HTML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML) are not encoded. What you're seeing is correct; the entities should be encoded within your XMLType object.

If you want to see the decoded entities you can use the deprecated `extractvalue` function:

```
SQL> select extractvalue(xmltype('<test>6''4"</test>'), '/test') from dual;

EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE('<TEST>6''4"</TEST>'),'/TEST')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6'4"
```

Or an XMLQuery, with XMLCast to do the decoding as part of converting to a plain string:

```
SQL> select xmlcast(xmlquery('/test/text()' passing xmltype('<test>6''4"</test>')
  2  returning content) as varchar2(10)) from dual;

XMLCAST(XM
----------
6'4"
```

---

Based on how you're using the data in your procedure, you can change form using `extract()` to `xmlcast(xmlquery(...) as ...)`. You can't call that natively in PL/SQL (as far as I can tell) so you'll need a context switch to select from dual; and it also doesn't seem to like concatenating the index value within the command - not quite sure why, but I've had to use a variable to hold the constructed XPath.

As an example, if you had something similar to this - with the values being passed to your procedure in your real case - you'd still have the encoded value:

```
DECLARE
  ncoXml XMLType := XMLType(q'[<victims><victim index="1"><name>Peter O'Toole</name></victim></victims>]');
  victimIndex pls_integer := 1;
  victimName varchar2(200);
BEGIN
  victimName := SUBSTR(ncoXml.EXTRACT('/victims/victim[@index="'
    || TO_CHAR(victimIndex) || '"]/name/text()').GETSTRINGVAL(), 1, 200);
  dbms_output.put_line(victimName);
END;
/

Peter O&apos;Toole
```

And an XMLCast variant might look like:

```
DECLARE
  ncoXml XMLType := XMLType(q'[<victims><victim index="1"><name>Peter O'Toole</name></victim></victims>]');
  victimIndex pls_integer := 1;
  victimName varchar2(200);
  xPath varchar2(200);
BEGIN
  xPath := '/victims/victim[@index="' || victimIndex || '"]/name/text()';
  select xmlcast(xmlquery(xPath passing ncoXml returning content) as varchar2(200))
  into victimName
  from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(victimName);
END;
/

Peter O'Toole
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

This is how we are retrieving the name from the XML.

    victimName := SUBSTR(ncoXml.EXTRACT('/victims/victim[' || TO_CHAR(victimIndex) || ']/name/text()').GETSTRINGVAL(), 1, 200);

Then uses that variable name to update/insert.  I was always under the impression it was best to store un-encoded data in the database and encode it before you display it.

Comment: Is there a way to change the stored procedure to store the data not encoded?

Comment: How is the procedure storing the data - as a simple insert into an XMLType column, as a CLOB column, with data extracted from the XML and put into relational tables? If it is an XMLType column then it's correct to store the encoded entities, and you'll need to decode them when queried/extracted. Otherwise you can decode them as you translate the XML data into the CLOB or relational columns.

Comment: The field is a varchar(200)  <br/>

They do something like this...

 BEGIN
      victimName := SUBSTR(ncoXml.EXTRACT('/victims/victim[' || TO_CHAR(victimIndex) || ']/name/text()').GETSTRINGVAL(), 1, 200);
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        NULL;
    END;
<br/><br/>

Then do a standard insert/update lower.

Comment: @frmrock164 - then they can use the `XMLCast` option in the answer to get the decoded value, instead of `extract`? (Or deprecated `extractValue`).

Comment: @frmrock164 - OK, it wasn't quite as straightforward as I assumed from PL/SQL, partly because of your victimIndex. I've updated the answer with an example. I've also assumed you're actually looking a matching victim node based on an attribute, from your square brackets, and I've made up a name for that.

Comment: Alex...First off.. Thank you for your help.

I updated the stored proc to get the decoded value this way.

      victimName := SUBSTR(utl_i18n.unescape_reference(ncoXml.EXTRACT('/victims/victim[' || TO_CHAR(victimIndex) || ']/name/text()').GETSTRINGVAL()), 1, 200);

Do you see anything wrong with this? Seems to work fine.

Comment: @frmrock164 - extract is deprecated. It ought to work OK, but if you're changing it anyway, why not switch to the current functionality?

Comment: Very true, however this is just one field of many of this large stored proc.  I was just trying to make the minimal change, but I will just bit the bullet and change it all.  Thanks again for all your help!